# No.of Inactive session increased while connection made using BoneCP - for every run

Tags: java, database-connection, jdbc-odbc, bonecp

I have connected Oracle db with Application. For each and every run, no.of inactive sessions are increased and that means the old sessions are not reused and new three connection s are created for every insert/update operation. Only after shut downing Application server everything reset and comes to normal.

If it continues, whether it raise any problem?. Any idea for why this happened and 
Anyway to rectify the issue?

### This is basic config for JDBC connection for Oracle

```
Class.forName(driverClass);
BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl");
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);
config.setPartitionCount(1);
config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(2);
config.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(4);
config.setAcquireIncrement(3);
config.setLazyInit(true);
config.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
config.setLogStatementsEnabled(true);
poolManager = new BoneCP(config);
```

### Query

select * from v$session where username='ORACLE_DB';

```
"SADDR" "SID"   "SERIAL#"   "AUDSID"    "PADDR" "USER#" "USERNAME"  "COMMAND"   "OWNERID"   "TADDR" "LOCKWAIT"  "STATUS"    "SERVER"    "SCHEMA#"   "SCHEMANAME"    "OSUSER"    "PROCESS"   "MACHINE"   "PORT"  "TERMINAL"  "PROGRAM"   "TYPE"  "SQL_ADDRESS"   "SQL_HASH_VALUE"    "SQL_ID"    "SQL_CHILD_NUMBER"  "SQL_EXEC_START"    "SQL_EXEC_ID"   "PREV_SQL_ADDR" "PREV_HASH_VALUE"   "PREV_SQL_ID"   "PREV_CHILD_NUMBER" "PREV_EXEC_START"   "PREV_EXEC_ID"  "PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID" "PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID" "PLSQL_OBJECT_ID"   "PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID"   "MODULE"    "MODULE_HASH"   "ACTION"    "ACTION_HASH"   "CLIENT_INFO"   "FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE"  "ROW_WAIT_OBJ#" "ROW_WAIT_FILE#"    "ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#"   "ROW_WAIT_ROW#" "TOP_LEVEL_CALL#"   "LOGON_TIME"    "LAST_CALL_ET"  "PDML_ENABLED"  "FAILOVER_TYPE" "FAILOVER_METHOD"   "FAILED_OVER"   "RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP"   "PDML_STATUS"   "PDDL_STATUS"   "PQ_STATUS" "CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION"    "CLIENT_IDENTIFIER" "BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS"   "BLOCKING_INSTANCE" "BLOCKING_SESSION"  "FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS" "FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE"   "FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION"    "SEQ#"  "EVENT#"    "EVENT" "P1TEXT"    "P1"    "P1RAW" "P2TEXT"    "P2"    "P2RAW" "P3TEXT"    "P3"    "P3RAW" "WAIT_CLASS_ID" "WAIT_CLASS#"   "WAIT_CLASS"    "WAIT_TIME" "SECONDS_IN_WAIT"   "STATE" "WAIT_TIME_MICRO"   "TIME_REMAINING_MICRO"  "TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO"    "SERVICE_NAME"  "SQL_TRACE" "SQL_TRACE_WAITS"   "SQL_TRACE_BINDS"   "SQL_TRACE_PLAN_STATS"  "SESSION_EDITION_ID"    "CREATOR_ADDR"  "CREATOR_SERIAL#"   "ECID"
000007FF657E9E78    32  17519   8268263 000007FF654EC488    574 "ORACLE_DB" 0   2147483644  ""  ""  "INACTIVE"  "DEDICATED" 574 "ORACLE_DB" "TestPC"    "1234"  "TESTPC-PC" 52779   "unknown"   "JDBC Thin Client"  "USER"  00  0   ""  ""  ""  ""  000007FF4B548518    1374653582  "cs6jdgt8yz34f" 0   24-03-14    16789303    ""  ""  ""  ""  "JDBC Thin Client"  2546894660  ""  0   ""  5403085 -1  0   0   0   5   24-03-14    3739    "NO"    "NONE"  "NONE"  "NO"    ""  "DISABLED"  "ENABLED"   "ENABLED"   0   ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  2045    345 "SQL*Net message from client"   "driver id" 1952673792  0000000074637000    "#bytes"    1   0000000000000001    ""  0   00  2723168908  6   "Idle"  0   3739    "WAITING"   3738938101  -1  0   "SYS$USERS" "DISABLED"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FIRST EXEC"    100 000007FF654EC488    233 ""
000007FF657E4198    34  36782   8268131 000007FF654E3098    574 "ORACLE_DB" 0   2147483644  ""  ""  "INACTIVE"  "DEDICATED" 574 "ORACLE_DB" "TestPC"    "1234"  "TESTPC-PC" 52675   "unknown"   "JDBC Thin Client"  "USER"  00  0   ""  0   ""  ""  00  0   ""  0   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "JDBC Thin Client"  2546894660  ""  0   ""  5402600 -1  0   0   0   115 24-03-14    4354    "NO"    "NONE"  "NONE"  "NO"    ""  "DISABLED"  "ENABLED"   "ENABLED"   0   ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  6   345 "SQL*Net message from client"   "driver id" 1952673792  0000000074637000    "#bytes"    1   0000000000000001    ""  0   00  2723168908  6   "Idle"  0   4353    "WAITING"   4353237602  -1  0   "SYS$USERS" "DISABLED"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FIRST EXEC"    100 000007FF654E3098    77  ""
000007FF657CFC88    41  44470   8268198 000007FF654EA3A8    574 "ORACLE_DB" 0   2147483644  ""  ""  "INACTIVE"  "DEDICATED" 574 "ORACLE_DB" "TestPC"    "1234"  "TESTPC-PC" 52708   "unknown"   "JDBC Thin Client"  "USER"  00  0   ""  ""  ""  ""  000007FF4B548518    1374653582  "cs6jdgt8yz34f" 0   24-03-14    16788295    ""  ""  ""  ""  "JDBC Thin Client"  2546894660  ""  0   ""  5402793 -1  0   0   0   5   24-03-14    4050    "NO"    "NONE"  "NONE"  "NO"    ""  "DISABLED"  "ENABLED"   "ENABLED"   0   ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  2023    345 "SQL*Net message from client"   "driver id" 1952673792  0000000074637000    "#bytes"    1   0000000000000001    ""  0   00  2723168908  6   "Idle"  0   4049    "WAITING"   4049292378  -1  0   "SYS$USERS" "DISABLED"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FIRST EXEC"    100 000007FF654EA3A8    76  ""
000007FF657C9FA8    43  57339   8268602 000007FF654F16B8    574 "ORACLE_DB" 0   2147483644  ""  ""  "INACTIVE"  "DEDICATED" 574 "ORACLE_DB" "TestPC"    "1234"  "TESTPC-PC" 52978   "unknown"   "JDBC Thin Client"  "USER"  00  0   ""  ""  ""  ""  000007FF4B548518    1374653582  "cs6jdgt8yz34f" 0   24-03-14    16790312    ""  ""  ""  ""  "JDBC Thin Client"  2546894660  ""  0   ""  5404182 -1  0   0   0   5   24-03-14    2180    "NO"    "NONE"  "NONE"  "NO"    ""  "DISABLED"  "ENABLED"   "ENABLED"   0   ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  "NO HOLDER" ""  ""  2017    345 "SQL*Net message from client"   "driver id" 1952673792  0000000074637000    "#bytes"    1   0000000000000001    ""  0   00  2723168908  6   "Idle"  0   2180    "WAITING"   2180168100  -1  0   "SYS$USERS" "DISABLED"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FIRST EXEC"    100 000007FF654F16B8    70  ""
```